# Chrome 62.x behaving badly with css transform and filter on images

Tags: css, google-chrome

The latest version of Chrome for MacOS (`Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)`) seems to behave badly with a combination of css `transform` and `filter` on images. The image either flickers as you scroll or just disappears all together. Here is the css I am using and a jsfiddle showing the issue.

```
.test {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(1deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 5px #000);
  margin: 40px 40px 1500px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vjb5uLkq/

Commenting either `transform` or `filter` out fixes the problem. Short of rotating/adding a drop shadow in photoshop, how could I fix this problem?

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(1deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 5px #000);
  margin: 40px 40px 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://placebear.com/200/300" class="test" />
</div>
```

Comment: there is no issue?

Comment: you see a slightly rotated image of bears with a drop-shadow and you are on chrome version 62.x?

Comment: yes i see a slightly rotated image of bears with shadow, no flickering when i scroll to the bottom and image does not vanish when i scroll back up. `Version 62.0.3202.94`

Comment: did u try disabling hardware acceleration?

Comment: Nice one :/ I can reproduce your problem with the same version, on Win 10. First I saw nothing while Firefox 56.x was fine, then I can see the bottom of the image (roughly bottom half of the bear). No flickering on JSFiddle but I've never seen the top of the image even while scrolling. Image seems to scroll under an opaque element. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/LOOeay) is different (!) and it depends on where the HTML/CSS/JS panes are! If on top I see nothing, on side it's flickering but I see the whole image. Strange. It's my work env so may have strange settings ;)

Comment: I just added your code here as a snippet: I can only see the top of the image (half the nose of the bear on top) and in full page I can see the whole page but it's still "laggy" when scrolling EDIT : did you test on a real HTML/CSS page, outside of those iframes Codepen, SO and JSFiddle use?

Comment: On Chrome `Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)` for me I see a clipped image, almost as if `overflow: hidden` is applied. Firefox shows the whole image.

Comment: @Hash - I tried that, no dice.

Comment: @FelipeAls I spotted it on a proper page initially though it wasn't a vanilla html/css page, it was on a react/less project I am working on. Your codepen is closer to what I am getting on my actual project.

Comment: @boz unable to replicate it

Comment: @Hash I did try various settings for `image-rendering` but none made a difference. I may just do the drop-shadow in photoshop and move on.

Comment: It should be reported as a bug: http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: @instead good call - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=786352

Comment: Further tests with a netbook: no problem with Chromium 61.0.3133.0 and Chrome Canary 64.0.3271.0 (Build officiel) canary (64 bits) in both your fiddle and my pen (I tested all 3 possible views with latter)

Comment: It worked fine for me on regular chrome 61.x 64bit on MacOS too. Lets see what happens to the bug report.